# using regex expressions to only select lines with an error code (-) and ignore others

Tags: regex, tivoli

I'm new to regex expressions and I need some help to capture only lines that have the (-999), and retrieve the number in parentheses in a line like "2016/99/99 12:00:0.999 2   1   **(-499)** Cannot open the message store with error code" 
This is for an ITM log monitor for Tivoli.

Comment: Have you tried anything? What works and what does not work?

Comment: I have tried:
REGEX error_log
 ^$"\([^\d]*(\d+)[^\d]*\)"$
 timestamp $1 CustomSlot1
 evtcategory $2 CustomSlot2
 severity "Error" CustomSlot3
 msg $7
 END

Comment: Please add that to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Would be nice if you had tried something yourself.. but anyway try this: `\((-.*?)\)`

This will capture anything negative that is between the brackets.

You never specified what language you were using, some languages use different regex engines and may or may not require delimiters - so this is a bit of a shot in the dark.

**Demo** - https://regex101.com/r/aD2lM3/2

Comment: Thanx,  I have been to that site a few times over the last few days, trying various things.  I have been able to get the part I'm looking for highlighted, but them I try it in the .fmt file, it shows syntax error, so I missing something

Comment: I'm not sure about .fmt files. But maybe you're missing the delimeters? try `/\((-.*?)\)/g`